# Showing attachment in edit view Rails 6 (active storage)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, edit, attachment, rails-activestorage

Situation:
I sucessfully upload a file called :physical_copy in my form partial "_a_partial.html.erb", which is used for creating new objects and editing existing objects at the same time

Code:

```
              <%= f.file_field :physical_copy,
                               required: true,
                               class: 'form-control',
                               value: @tax_relevant_document.physical_copy  %>
```

New & create works perfectly fine.

Problem:
The file is not shown and hence deleted when editing, which is not the planned behavior. I can work around by first downloading and "re-uploading" but this shouldn't be the normal behavior.

Guess:
This "value" thing looks awry to me but removal of the attribute didn't help.

I would like:

1. edit view to show the existing filename in the field as basically value representation
2. the form should include the existing attachment in the field

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and made it conditional, which works fine in my case:

```
<% if !object.attachment_attribute.attached? %>
  (File Field from above)
<% else # (attachment exists) %>
  <%=
    link_to(
      object.attachment_attribute.filename, 
      rails_blob_path(object.attachment_attribute, disposition: 'attachment')
    )
  %>
<% end %>
```

Basically the attachment for download!